# How to highlight a day which has an event in FullCalendar.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fullcalendar

I am using FullCalendar.js in my website. I have set events from backend. I want to change look of the day which has an event. In other words I need some sort of class where I have "fc-day" and an event in it.

[My code looks like and you see it on jsFiddle:](http://jsfiddle.net/6NShN/1/)

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    events: [{
        title: 'event1',
        start: '2013-01-01'
    }, {
        title: 'event2',
        start: '2013-12-05',
        end: '2013-12-07'
    }, {
        title: 'event3',
        start: '2013-12-15'
    }]
})
```

Comment: not single answer so far???

Comment: what look u want to change ? u can add .fc-event {background-color:red;} in ur page and it will make event color red. or use jquery select all div with this class and addClass what u want to set.

Comment: Check working demo here http://jsfiddle.net/subodhghulaxe/sj5CD/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I could not find a desired property or method to use in the documentation of Fullcalendar.

I came up with a kind of a messy solution: **adding a class by data-attributes:**

```
function addClassByDate(date) {
    var dataAttr = getDataAttr(date);
    $("[data-date='" + dataAttr + "']").addClass("hasEvent");
}

function getDataAttr(date) {
    return date.getFullYear() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + (date.getDate().toString().length === 2 ? date.getDate() : "0" + date.getDate());
};
```

It works fine for the settings, you've provided in your question.

The working example could be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/6NShN/9/

Comment: I had to change this to
`function getDataAttr(date) {
    return date.getFullYear() + "-" + ((date.getMonth()+1).toString().length === 2 ? (date.getMonth()+1) : "0" + (date.getMonth()+1)) + "-" + (date.getDate().toString().length === 2 ? date.getDate() : "0" + date.getDate());
};`

as the data-date attribute seems to use leading 0s for single digit months and Date.getMonth() is 0-indexed (eg. 0 == January), while data-date is 1-indexed (01 == January). Otherwise good solution.

Comment: This solution works to me but the last day in a couple days event's, has not got "hasEvent" class. Any help?

Comment: I set this before while in your fiddle:
            evFinishDate.setDate(evFinishDate.getDate()+1);

Answer (score 9):

You can use **[eventRender()](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/eventRender/)** property of Full Canendar.

This works for me with fullcalendar v2:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
         events: [
        {
            title  : 'event1',
            start  : '2014-04-01'
        },
        {
            title  : 'event2',
            start  : '2014-04-05',
        },
        {
            title  : 'event3',
            start  : '2014-04-15'
        }
    ],
    eventRender: function (event, element, view) { 
        // like that
        var dateString = moment(event.start).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
        $('#calendar').find('.fc-day-number[data-date="' + dateString + '"]').css('background-color', '#FAA732');
     }

});
```

> **Note:** You will need [**Moment**](http://momentjs.com/) library for this.

Comment: First thing to work in 2 weeks of looking. You are amazing. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

This is how I did it to give background color to each and every events.

[JS FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6NShN/23/)

```
events: [
     {
       title: 'Test1',
       start: new Date(2014, 2, 28, 12, 0),
       end: new Date(2014, 2, 30, 12, 0), 
       backgroundColor: '#80ACED',
     },
     {
       title: 'Test2',
       start: new Date(2014, 2, 14, 3, 55),
       end: new Date(2014, 2, 21, 12, 0), 
       backgroundColor: '#80ACED',
     },
     {
       title: 'Test3',
       start: new Date(2014, 2, 2, 12, 0),
       end: new Date(2014, 2, 2, 12, 0), 
       backgroundColor: '#E82525',
     }
       ]
```

Hope this helps.
Refer : http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/

Comment: He is looking to change the look of the day, not events.

Comment: I was looking for this thing from quite sometime, thanks bro

Answer (score 3):

Finally this is how it worked for me take a look at this

**[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/subodhghulaxe/sj5CD/)**

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
         events: [
        {
            title  : 'event1',
            start  : '2014-04-01'
        },
        {
            title  : 'event2',
            start  : '2014-04-05',
        },
        {
            title  : 'event3',
            start  : '2014-04-15'
        }
    ],
    eventRender: function (event, element, view) { 
        // like that
        var dateString = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
        view.element.find('.fc-day[data-date="' + dateString + '"]').css('background-color', '#FAA732');
     }

});
```

Comment: `formatDate()` is fullcalendar v1, with v2 it will not work, see http://fullcalendar.io/wiki/Upgrading-to-v2/

Answer (score 2):

weswesweswes is nearly correct view.element should be view.el

```
eventRender: function (event, element, view) { 

    var dateString = moment(event.start).format('YYYY-MM-DD');

    view.el.find('.fc-day[data-date="' + dateString + '"]').addClass('fc-has-event');

}
```

Answer (score 1):

None of these will work for >=v2.0, since fullCalendar started using moment.js for date formatting.

The following worked for me (passed to fullCalendar initialization function):

```
eventRender: function (event, element, view) { 

var dateString = moment(event.start).format('YYYY-MM-DD');

view.element.find('.fc-day[data-date="' + dateString + '"]').addClass('fc-has-event');

}
```

Comment: hi, its not worked for me on version 2.1. It says "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined fullcalendar"

Answer (score 0):

You can add class on base of the fullcalender .fc-event class its not direct approach but its works.

[**Fiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/6NShN/11/)

```
   $(document).ready(function (){ 
   $(".fc-event").addClass("myclass");
  });
```

Comment: which version are you talking about ?

Answer (score 0):

Heres another Fiddle  **[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6NShN/14/)**

Just by adding

```
textColor: 'white',
backgroundColor:'purple'
```

You can change the style

**JS code:**

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({

    eventSources: [

        // your event source
        {
            events: [
        {
            title  : 'event1',
            start  : '2013-01-01'
        },
        {
            title  : 'event2',
            start  : '2013-12-05',
            end    : '2013-12-07'
        },
        {
            title  : 'event3',
            start  : '2013-12-15'
        }],

            textColor: 'white',
            backgroundColor:'purple'
        }

        // any other event sources...

    ]

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Fullcalendar v2, for agendaWeek view:

```
eventRender: function(event, element, view ){
    if(view.name=='agendaWeek') {
        var weekdays = new Array('sun', 'mon', 'tue', 'wed', 'thu', 'fri', 'sat');
        var eventweekday = $.fullCalendar.moment(event.start).format('d');
        $('.fc-'+weekdays[eventweekday]).css('background-color', '#FFC');
    }
},
```

Highlights all days with events.

[image: example fullcalendar day highlight]

Answer (score 0):

Had this same issue and had found a bunch of solutions for older versions of FullCalendar (which seemed a bit hacky anyway). However, in v5 you can use eventDidMount and traverse up the DOM to the day cell.

JS Code:

```
eventDidMount: function(info) {
    $(info.el).closest(".fc-daygrid-day").addClass("has-event");
}
```